# Unable to pass value to a cursor in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OM_TEST AS 
 CURSOR lcu_cust_site_ship (
                                p_cust_account_id  IN  NUMBER
                              , p_location_ship    IN  VARCHAR2
                              )
    IS
        SELECT HCSU.site_use_id
        FROM   hz_cust_site_uses_all HCSU, hz_cust_acct_sites_all CAS
        WHERE  HCSU.location   = p_location_ship
        AND    HCSU.SITE_USE_CODE = 'SHIP_TO'
        AND    HCSU.cust_acct_site_id = CAS.cust_acct_site_id
        AND    CAS.cust_account_id = p_cust_account_id;


ln_cust_site_ship   NUMBER:=0;

BEGIN
 OPEN lcu_cust_site_ship (217162, lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location);
 FETCH lcu_cust_site_ship INTO ln_cust_site_ship;

 CLOSE lcu_cust_site_ship;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  ('lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location: '||lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  ('ln_cust_site_ship: '||ln_cust_site_ship);
 EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR IN SHIP TO LOCATION ');
 END;
```

Here `lr_om_order_index` is a record index which contains the value of ship to location.

Now the output which is got is

> lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location: 6698
>
> ln_cust_site_ship:
>
> ERROR IN SHIP TO LOCATION.

Please help and guide me.I am unable to find out the error.

> If I pass value 6698 instead of lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location in the
>
> cursor,then it is working properly.

Comment: Your use of `when others` is not going to make debugging any easier. Change the line in your exception to give you a meaningful error essage, something like: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR IN SHIP TO LOCATION - '||SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM);`

Comment: Ok thanks.Now the output is ERROR IN SHIP TO_LOCATION - 100 ORA-01403: no data found.

Comment: Please include the whole code with  lr_om_order_index - where it is declared  and opened

Comment: Does the type of HCSU.location match lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location or is there an implicit conversion of NUMBER to VARCHAR happening?

Comment: @kayakpim-yes it is matching.Both the datatype is varchar2

Comment: @Mina.Its a very huge code.I have just the posted the part which contains the error.i just want to know what can be the possible errors in this type of scenario.

Comment: `No Data Found` basically means there is a `SELECT INTO`  statement somewhere that doesn't return any rows. Get rid of the exception block completely here. You are not doing anything meaningful to handle the error. At least that way you would get to know the line number where the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the cursor after DBMS_OUT should help

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, so very likely your problem is that location column datatype is not matching lr_om_order_index record type. You should check both declarations. Probably ship_to_location is CHAR or some similar problem

```
cREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OM_TEST AS 
CURSOR lcu_cust_site_ship (
                            p_cust_account_id  IN  NUMBER
                          , p_location_ship    IN  VARCHAR2
                          )
IS
    SELECT 1 as site_use_id
    FROM   dual
    WHERE  6698   = p_location_ship;

 ln_cust_site_ship   NUMBER:=0;

  BEGIN
    for lr_om_order_index in (select to_char(6698) ship_to_location from     dual) loop

 OPEN lcu_cust_site_ship (217162, lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location);
 FETCH lcu_cust_site_ship INTO ln_cust_site_ship;

 CLOSE lcu_cust_site_ship;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  ('lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location:    '||lr_om_order_index.ship_to_location);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  ('ln_cust_site_ship: '||ln_cust_site_ship);
end loop;

EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR IN SHIP TO LOCATION ');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks @Mina.I found out the problem and solution as well.Actually there was a space after the value of ship_to_location column in the table from which lr_om_order_index was fetching .So I used RTRIM which resolved this problem.